# Transition between variables R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, tidyr

I want to calculate summary of the transition between variables. I have the dataset which looks like:

```
id x.2012 y.2012 x.2013 y.2013
 1      1      0      0      1 
 2      0      1      1      0
 3      0      1      1      0
 4      1      0      1      0
```

And I want to find a transition table:

```
        x.2013 y.2013
x.2012       1      1
y.2012       2      0
```

So, it calculates how much values changed for `x`, so it's zero changes of `y` to `y` for the following year and 2 for the `y -> x`.

I have no idea how to calculate such a table, I was looking through [`reshape2`](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html) and [`tidyr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) documentation, but with no success.

---

Ideally, I'm looking for a package like `reshape` (I can't think of keywords for Google search of this...) which have similar to `cast` function, with `fun` taking subset of `my.df`:

```
modern.cast(my.df, .(x.2012, y.2012) ~ .(x.2013, y.2013), fun)
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: @Roland I can manually calculate with a loops, but this isn't a good, neither an efficient solution.

Comment: My point is that we prefer to see some effort. It's slightly better now. But showing a `for` loop would also be good. It might be trivial to translate that to Rcpp which would make it very efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution could be

```
res <- data.frame(t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) names(df[-1])[x != 0])))
library(reshape2)
dcast(res, X1 ~ X2)
#       X1 x.2013 y.2013
# 1 x.2012      1      1
# 2 y.2012      2      0
```

---

Alternative approach would be using `which` (which could be potentially more efficient)

```
indx <- which(df[-1] != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
res <- data.frame(matrix(names(df)[-1][indx[order(indx[, 1]), 2]], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
dcast(res, X1 ~ X2)
#       X1 x.2013 y.2013
# 1 x.2012      1      1
# 2 y.2012      2      0
```

Comment: It works for me for data set with even more variables, but can you add some more info on why it works? I don't understand why the `res` data.frame is needed...

Comment: Which solution you didn't understand, the first or the second? The reason for `data.frame` is because `dcast` accepts only `data.frame`s.

Comment: I mean the `apply` one.

Comment: The `apply` one is just checking which columns are not equal to zero per each row.